# I am trying to insert numbers in order, into a div body

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function yHandler(){ 
///page scroll loader
var statusloader = document.getElementById('statusloader');
var contentHeight = statusloader.offsetHeight;
var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
var i = 1;
if(y >= contentHeight){
// Ajax call to get more status data goes here
statusloader.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">'+ i++ +'</div>';}
}
window.onscroll = yHandler;


statusloader.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">i++</div>';}
```

this is the line that creates the divs. I have i++ in there to create the number 1, and then on the next div it should say number 2. bu ti am having trouble getting any number to come out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the string like:

```
statusloader.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">' + i++ + '</div>'
```

The problem is you are defining the variable i as a local variable and therefore it will always be set back to 1 if the function yhandler is called.

Just put the var i = 1 above the function definition

Comment: it is coming out blank. no numbers

Comment: well is the variable 'i' somewhere defined in your code?

Comment: var i = 1; but then it just repeats 1

Comment: Where did you define your i variable, i cant see it in your updated post

Comment: i have deleted the i variable but i just put it back for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131384/discussion-between-peter-and-dzdomi).

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 1; //place here it just ok   
function yHandler(){ 
///page scroll loader
var statusloader = document.getElementById('statusloader');
var contentHeight = statusloader.offsetHeight;
var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
//var i = 1;
if(y >= contentHeight){
// Ajax call to get more status data goes here
statusloader.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">'+ i++ +'</div>';
}
}
```